# Should I try to have positive standing with all four major factions?

Tags: eve-online

This is a simple question, but I can't find a decent answer.

I have recently started to play Eve Online as a Caldari capsuleer, and I am currently doing lvl 3 missions in a Drake.

As I didn't pay much attention to faction standings at the beginning, I am now at -2.03 towards the Gallente Federation, and I'm starting to wonder if I should try to get this standing positive again.

As far as I have understood, the only reliable way to gain faction standing, apart epic arcs or factional warfare is doing storyline missions, which is going to take some time to go from -2 to 0.

So, does it really worth it to manage to get a positive standing towards all four major factions ?

Comment: The problem with Storyline missions is that while increasing a faction standing, it does decrease your standing toward this faction enemies. So, storylining for the gallente would decrease your Caldari standing, and (to a lesser extent) your Amarr standing. My own advice would be to kill that faction foe rats, but you'll need to kill thousands of them...

Comment: As long as you're not below -4 standing, you still have access to all that faction systems... As long as you're carefull enough to not drop down you standings anymore, you'll be fine, and there are no good reason to try to go back to positive standings.

Comment: Well, I'm aware of the backside it could have on Caldari standing. But AFAIK, the standing decrease is lower than the standing increase, thus allowing having all four standings positive at the same time.

Comment: But you'll have to run countless storylines, and since you only obtain rights to do one storyline each 15 (i don't exactly remember) normal missions, it will take you a loooooooooooong time...

Comment: @Lysarion: Your comments are actually complete answers. I'd recommend posting them as answers so they can be voted up!

Comment: I'm not sure about myself posting my comments as an answer, since i'm higly subjective, due to my really lazy side... I just don't see the use of going through the grind of lvl1, then lvl2, then lvl3, then lvl4 and lvl4 storylines for about a month to pass from -2 to approximately 0... (Add one more month if you're stating at lvl3)

Comment: By the way,  the question will probably become "localised in time", because there are a lot of forum threads about a modification about CONCORD reaction time. It should become dependent of your standing to the faction owning sovereignity over the system. Thus, having a bad standing would mean that you could be easily ganked, even in HiSec...

Comment: @Lysarion can you link to some of that info?

Comment: Side note for the op,unless you are worried about trading, researching, or manufacturing in at least one of every single faction's regions, there is little point to doing this. Even then, the benefits are fairly low.

Comment: @Andy: sorry, my computer got destroyed (you don't want to know how...), and i lost the link. I tried to find it again, but didn't manage to. I remember seeing a thread about it in the official forums, and there was a side-note in a really old devblog, but it seems that possibility got buried...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've thought of this myself after realizing that my gallante standing was -7 (running with a Caldari mission corp will get you there pretty fast), and eventually decided to just pump up my social skills. Its quicker then trying to get your standing up, and unless you've completely buggered your standing with a faction you shouldn't be killed on site if you happen to wander into space claimed by a faction that doesn't' like you too much.

The only time I'd worry about having great standing with all four factions is if your character is going super hardcore into industry(and I mean 100% non-stop indy character). If you're in EVE for the pew pew, just keeping your faction standing around the -2/3 area for everyone is good enough to not have your ships popped on sight should say, a war target fly through space that you'd get popped on sight for.