# Is being a factions enemy hard?

Tags: eve-online

I'm a gallentean flying for the minmatar. So both doing missions with my friends (gallente) and on my own (minmatar, for LP) get me in bad books with the amar.

The wiki recomended doing missions for all 4 factions to avoid being seen as a criminal by them. but do i have to? i dont like the amar.

What type of problems do i have to excpect if i keep this up? is the imperial navy strong? or similar to running a mission? is the security status making it harder? (like .5 is like level 1 mission while .9 like a level 4) will concord be angry with me for killing amar imperials?

Comment: This question has many interesting comments on the subject: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19256/should-i-try-to-have-positive-standing-with-all-four-major-factions

Comment: the comment on CONCORD was intresting. and it did provide a means to keep reputation up with other factions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you keep doing missions, especially storyline ones, for the Minmatar will eventually have you as persona non grata for the Amarr. Depending on just how much your'e hated, you may be shot on sight by the ships that guard gates in Amarr site (worse standing, lower sec level that you'll be popped on sight).

There's a very slim chance that you'll be able to tank the Imperial defense force, but mostly be prepared to die and die quickly. The good thing is that CONCORD will not jump in.

Comment: is the lower the sec, the more likely i will be popped or the other way around?

Comment: Sorry it is the other way around. A .5 for example will be "safer" then a 1.0 for example.